# What is the reason for setting the movie storyline 8 years apart?

Tags: analysis, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, it is stated many times that it's 8 years after the end of *The Dark Knight*. This personally threw the storyline off for me. Why did it need to be 8 years after? 4 years would have surely been enough time difference for the storyline that played out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Christopher Nolan's answer**](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/GraphicCity/news/?a=64299) to the 8 year gap is:

> ***It's partly about a physical and emotional toll and it's partly about being true to the end of [The Dark Knight].***
>
> *What you have at the end of 'The Dark Knight' is an ending that hangs very much on substantial sacrifice to achieve a certain end and for that to have meaning, it has to work in some sense, it has to have been successful. And **I didn't want to just abandon that and pick up a new story with a whole new set of ideas.***
>
> *So for me, that lead to the 8 year gap, it lead to the idea of Bruce Wayne, shut away in self-imposed exile because he's hung up his cape and cowl. He's living in a world, at least superficially, that doesn't need Batman but he hasn't moved on, he hasn't moved on as Alfred points out, he hasn't moved on emotionally or in a practical sense.*

He reiterates this in [**another interview**](http://blastr.com/2011/12/chris-nolan-explains-that.php):

> *... I think what we're saying is that **for Batman and Commissioner Gordon, there's a big sacrifice, a big compromise, at the end of the 'The Dark Knight'**, and for that to mean something, that sacrifice has to work, and Gotham has to get better in a sense. They have to achieve something for the ending of that film—and the feeling at the end of that film—to have validity.*
>
> ***Their sacrifice has to have meaning, and it takes time to establish that and to show that, and that's the primary reason we did that.***
>
> *It's a time period that is not so far ahead that we would have to do crazy makeup or anything—which I think would be distracting...*

The last sentence sounds like he had thought about an even bigger gap, but decided against it because he wanted to avoid *'old people make-up'*.

Answer (score 11):

I think story-wise these things needed to happen:

- The Harvey Dent Act had to have a real effect on Gotham's crime rate.
- Harvey Dent himself had to become a legend.
- The Batman's own legend had to fade away.
- Talia al Ghul had to become old enough to be part of the story.

Whether 4 years would've been enough for all this to happen is debatable IMO, especially for the first part. Laws take a long time to have noticeable effects. So 8 years seemed reasonable to me.

Comment: The movie made it seem like the Harvey Dent Act basically wiped out crime over night not slowly over eight years. Harvey Dent was a legend as soon as his funeral was over. Batman had only been around for 1 year according to this http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8196/talia-and-bane-age-problems Talia would have been old enough by the end of Dark Knight and definitely 4 years later as well as 8.

Comment: I would add that setting "The Dark Knight Rises" 8 years after makes more believable Bruce's injury in the knee that it would be after only 4 years.

Answer (score 7):

While the internal plot-driven reasons in the previous answer make sense, there is another reason why the period was a long one.

Nolan's partial inspiration seems to have been the fantastic Frank Miller comic, *The Dark Knight Returns* (which also inspired the *tone* of the Tim Burton Batman movies and went some way to revivifying the whole Batman comic franchise) which has a long-retired Batman returning from his retirement due to serious new threats to the city. While the actual plot is very different, there are significant *thematic* similarities, including the fact that Batman is not as capable as he used to be and is facing a lead villain who is, in many ways, his equal. Much of the thematic similarity just would not have worked if Batman had returned too soon.

Comment: 8 years pushes it though. 4 years is plenty of time. In the comic referenced Bruce Wayne is in his 60's. I just don't see Bruce Wayne not doing anything for 8 years. He didn't run his company or see anyone except Alfred.